# Call one constructor from the body of another in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

I need to call one constructor from the body of another one. How can I do that?

Basically

```
class foo {
    public foo (int x, int y)
    {
    }

    public foo (string s)
    {
        // ... do something

        // Call another constructor
        this (x, y); // Doesn't work
        foo (x, y); // neither
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a constructor like public foo (int x, int y , string s)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can't.

You'll have to find a way to chain the constructors, as in:

```
public foo (int x, int y) { }
public foo (string s) : this(XFromString(s), YFromString(s)) { ... }
```

or move your construction code into a common setup method, like this:

```
public foo (int x, int y) { Setup(x, y); }
public foo (string s)
{
   // do stuff
   int x = XFromString(s);
   int y = YFromString(s);
   Setup(x, y);
}

public void Setup(int x, int y) { ... }
```

Comment: Note that in general, a setup method would be unable to write to `readonly` variables, but a constructor can pass `readonly` variables as a `ref` parameters to a setup method which would then be able to write to its `ref` parameters even though they're read-only variables.

Comment: The Setup method should in most cases be private

Comment: Watch that In the first solution `XFromString` and `YFromString` must be static methods. That's my favorite way to do it!

Answer (score 44):

`this(x, y)` is right, but it has to be before the start of the constructor body:

```
public Foo(int x, int y)
{
    ...
}

public Foo(string s) : this(5, 10)
{
}
```

Note that:

- You can only chain to one constructor, either `this` or `base` - that constructor can chain to another one, of course.
- The constructor body executes *after* the chained constructor call. There is no way to execute the constructor body first.
- You can't use `this` within the arguments to the other constructor, including calling instance methods - but you *can* call static methods.
- Any instance variable initializers *are* executed before the chained call.

I have a bit more information in my [article about constructor chaining](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/constructors.html).

Comment: That's especially annoying when you have something like this: `class A{ public A(IEnumerable<int> items) {...} public A(MyClass c) : this(c.Items) { ... } }`. Any null check in the second ctor will only be executed after `c` is accessed. The second ctor will throw a NRE if c is null, instead of the preferred `ArgumentNullException`. If you want to keep your fields read only, there is no other possibility than to implement the same logic in two ctors. Or *is* there a better way to do this?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yes there is. Have a generic extension method which checks for nullity but returns the original value otherwise. Then you can do `this(c.ThrowIfNull("c").Items)`

Comment: Thanks, that was the only thing I could come up with, too. Just wanted to edit my comment... Wasn't sure if it is a good way though, because I haven't seen it anywhere so far...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I think it's okay, yeah.

Comment: One question: Is the evaluation order of parameters fixed or an implementation detail that could change? Because if you need to access multiple properties, it get's quite unwieldy: `public PcmSample(IPcmSample other) : this(other.ThrowIfNull("other").Channels, other.ThrowIfNull("other").Items)`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: The arguments are evaluated in textual order, just as for arguments to method calls etc. Note that this can be a different order to the order in which the *parameters* are declared if you use named arguments.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Just the first one for that parameter, yes. If there are other parameters which need checking, they need one call each.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20181103085311/http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html For the article referenced at the bottom.

Comment: @HenryMalinowski: Thanks - have updated the link to the non-Yoda location.

Answer (score 7):

To call both base and this class constructor explicitly you need to use syntax given below (note, that in C# you can not use it to initialize fields like in C++):

```
class foo
{
    public foo (int x, int y)
    {
    }

    public foo (string s) : this(5, 6)
    {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

//EDIT: Noticed, that you've used x,y in your sample. Of course, values given when invoking ctor such way can't rely on parameters of other constructor, they must be resolved other way (they do not need to be constants though as in edited code sample above). If `x` and `y` is computed from `s`, you can do it this way:

```
public foo (string s) : this(GetX(s), GetY(s))
```

Comment: Little remark: public foo(string s) : this(x, y) will not work. public foo(string s, int x, int y) : this(x, y) will compile

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that `GetX()` and `GetY()` must be static methods (obvious, hopefully: until ctor completion, there is no instance on which to invoke instance methods).

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported - see *[Constructors in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html)*.

However, you can implement a common (private) method which you call from the different constructors...

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this problem a time or two myself... I ended up having to extract whatever logic I needed in that other constructor into a `private void` method and calling it in both places.

```
class foo
{
  private void Initialize(int x, int y)
  {
    //... do stuff
  }

  public foo(int x, int y)
  {
    Initialize(x, y);
  }

  public foo(string s_
  {
    // ... do stuff

    Initialize(x, y)
    // ... more stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a note in [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke) of `MethodBase.Invoke` in MSDN

> If this method overload is used to invoke an instance constructor, the
>   object supplied for obj is reinitialized; that is, all instance
>   initializers are executed. The return value is null. If a class
>   constructor is invoked, the class is reinitialized; that is, all class
>   initializers are executed. The return value is null.

I.e. you can get Constructor's method by reflection and call it through `Invoke` in your new constructor's body. **But I haven't try it**. And, of course, this solution have a lot of drawbacks.