# Calling Constructor with in constructor in same class c# and calling to base Constructor in the same Constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I have `class A` which inherits from `class B`.
`class B` has the following Constructor:

```
public class B
{
    public B(int num) { ... }
}
```

Class `A` has a *default constructor*.
Is there a way to implement a Constructor in `class A` which calls the *base constructor* from `class B` and calls the *default constructor* from `class A`?
Something which can use `base` and `this`:

```
public class A : B
{
    public A() { ... }

    public A(int num) : base(num), this()
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: What if something calls the `A()` constructor directly? You're proposing that it not invoke a base class constructor at all?

Comment: Is this you're looking for => 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575739/call-one-constructor-from-the-body-of-another-in-c-sharp/7575773#7575773

Comment: This can't be done. You can't chain a constructor to more than one other constructor at the time, and unless the base class (`B` in your case) have only only a single, parameter-less constructor, the derived class `A` constructor must be chained to a specific constructor eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code *doesn't compile*: there is no way for `public A()` to call base `B(int num)` constructor (what should be passed as `num`?)

You can move logic from `A()` to `A(int num)` and use constructor chaining to implement `A()`

```
public class A : B
{
    public A(): this(0) {} //TODO: provide default num here

    public A(int num) : base(num)
    { 
        //TODO: implement logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use static constructor like this

```
public class B
    {
        public B(int num)
        {
            Console.Write("B");
        }
    }

    public class A : B
    {
        static A()
        {
            Console.Write("A");
        }

        public A(int num) : base(num)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: A static constructor is not a replacement for an instance constructor. It can only instantiate static members.